# Prove that $\sqrt{3}\cos(x) + \sin(x) = 2\cos\left(x- \frac{\pi}{6}\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm stuck on a trigonometry question. The formulae I have been given don't seem to help so I had to come here.

The question is:

> Prove that $\sqrt{3}\cos(x) + \sin(x) = 2\cos\left(x- \frac{\pi}{6}\right)$

If these formulae can be used I would be glad if you could show me how:

- $\cos(2x) = 2\cos^2(x) - 1$
- $\cos(2x) = 1 - 2\sin^2(x)$
- $\cos^2(x) = \frac 12(1 + \cos(2x))$
- $\sin^2(x) = \frac 12(1 - \cos(2x))$

Comment: **hint:** More generally speaking, $cos(a+b) = cos(a)cos(b) -sin(a)sin(b)$. The $cos(2x)$ expansion is just a consequence of this formula where $a = b = x$

Comment: @Bye_World thanks for your efforts ;-)

Comment: @infinitylord thanks for help

Comment: @Bye_World thanks lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the right side you can use:
\begin{equation}
\cos(\alpha-\beta)=\cos\alpha\cos\beta+\sin\alpha\sin\beta\\
\end{equation}

In this case:
\begin{equation}
\cos(x-\frac{\pi}{6})=\cos x\cos\frac{\pi}{6}+\sin x\sin\frac{\pi}{6}\\
\cos(x-\frac{\pi}{6})=\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\cos x+\frac{1}{2}\sin x
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks! I'm beginning to understand although how is step 1 simplified down to step 2? I can see why you are dividing both sides by two, but I don't understand how the LHS can be substituted in there.

Comment: Your equation is actually an identity, so I considered only the RHS applying the "cosine of a difference" formula: $2\cos(x-\frac{\pi}{6})=2(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\cos x+\frac{1}{2}\sin x)$. Now you can see that RHS and LHS are equal